# Why the integration command for this function gives no answer?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have a function `wfVAR2[r1, r2]` which has the following form:

```
wfVAR2[r1_, r2_]:=(-(1/(r1 r2))
 2 E^(-3.99999997*10^-8 r1 - 1.24 r1^2 - 0.2379728 r1 r2 - 
   1.24 r2^2) π (-4.202160919 E^(
     0.1189864 r1^2 + 
      r1 (1.999999985*10^-8 + 0.4759456 r2) + (-1.999999985*10^-8 + 
         0.1189864 r2) r2) + 
    4.202160919 E^(
     0.1189864 r1^2 + 0.1189864 r2^2 + 1.999999985*10^-8 (r1 + r2)) - 
    2.159230221*10^-7 E^(r1 (3.99999997*10^-8 + 0.2379728 r2))
      Erfi[2.899020819*10^-8 - 0.3449440534 r1 + 0.3449440534 r2] + 
    2.159230221*10^-7 E^(r1 (3.99999997*10^-8 + 0.2379728 r2))
      Erfi[2.899020819*10^-8 - 0.3449440534 (r1 + r2)] - 
    2.64697796*10^-23 E^(r1 (3.99999997*10^-8 + 0.2379728 r2))
      Erfi[2.899020819*10^-8 - 0.3449440534 Sqrt[r1^2 + r2^2]]))
```

when I try this

```
gVAR = Integrate[wfVAR2[r1, r2], {r2, r-r1, r+r1}]
```

it's really amazing that I get no answer! I really don't know what is the problem?! Any idea?

Comment: The problem is that there is no answer... You will have to resort to numeric evaluation.

Comment: @Andreas Why? Is this natural? I hadn't ever seen such a thing where an integration command gives nothing, it gave some errors instead.

Comment: @Wisdom yes it's very common for instance: `Integrate[Gamma[x], {x, 2, 3}]`. Integrating higher transcendental functions with expressions containing  `Erfi` is often very hard or impossible. In some cases these integrals don't even exist in terms of finite elementary functions (that are not expressed as series) - provably so, see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use approximate floating-point numbers in an exact solver, you invite trouble.  It's hard to figure out whether accumulated round-off error is causing failure or if the problem simply cannot be solved symbolically by Wolfram.  Mathematica has improved over the years (imo) its ability to handle FP numbers in exact solvers, but round-off error is an error that creeps into FP computations. It can't completely be avoided, and it can have consequences.

Here are two ways to check the symbolic solver's capability: First, replace the FP coefficients by rational numbers via `Rationalize`.  It runs into computational limits, unfortunately.

```
gVAR = Integrate[
  Rationalize[Rationalize@wfVAR2[r1, r2], 10^-16], {r2, r - r1, 
   r + r1}, Assumptions -> r > r1 > 0]
```

> `PolynomialGCD::lrgexp` :  Exponent is out of bounds for function PolynomialGCD.
> ...[several more]...

[image]

Another is to replace the FP coefficients with parameters.

```
coeffs = DeleteDuplicates@
  Cases[wfVAR2[r1, r2], x_Real :> Abs[x], Infinity]
nf = Nearest[coeffs -> "Index"];
gVAR = Integrate[
  wfVAR2[r1, r2] /. x_Real :> Sign[x] a @@ nf[Abs[x]],
  {r2, r - r1, r + r1},
  Assumptions -> 
   Flatten@{r > r1 > 0, 
     MapIndexed[#1/2 < a @@ #2 < 3 #/2 &, 
      Rationalize[SetPrecision[coeffs, 3], 0]]}
  ]
```

[image]

It seems Mathematica does not know how to solve it.  Sometimes a clever transformation can help, but I have none to suggest.  It's also possible that if the parameters of the source of the integral were kept in symbolic form until the end, the integrand might be more tractable.